# Can something besides leaks cause memory to grow indefinitely in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, instruments

I have a game loop which I've put inside another loop like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
 {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Game *game = [[Game alloc] init];
    while ([game isActive])
       [game nextRound];
    [game release];

    [pool release]; 
 }
```

But I noticed in activity monitor that the real memory used grows indefinitely, and the app eventually crashes when it reaches around 1GB of memory. Instruments didn't report any leaks. The clang static analyzer didn't report leaks either.

My questions are:

1. Does instruments always find all memory leaks?
2. Could there be another reason for this indefinite increase of memory?

**edit:**

As pointed out by @Phillips, the reason was the zombies flag! After turning it off, the memory footprint is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruments can also be used to look at memory allocation.  Try looking at the number of live objects when your memory has grown to see what kind of things are still active.

It's not necessarily a leak causing memory to grow.  For example, if you have some object created during `nextRound` that retains your `Game` object, then releasing it in the code you posted might not result in a `dealloc`.

Comment: Thanks, Phillips! The Game object is only referenced from this code. Does the "# Living" column contain the number of currently available objects?

Comment: Yes.  If you click on the little arrow beside the category name it will show you a list of objects of that type.  If you then click the little arrow beside one of the addresses, it will give you that instance's creation and retain information.

Comment: Wow, then non of the objects are actually released! even though all dealloc methods are invoked! I may have some circular references somewhere, I have to dig more. Thanks again!

Comment: If it actually hits a `dealloc` it should be gone from memory unless you have zombies turned on.  When you drill down there will be a non-zero reference count for the ones taking up space.

Comment: ZOMBIES!!! That's the reason! I totally forgot about this flag. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have a big while loop in there, with no autorelease pool inside. Try

```
while ([game isActive]) {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   [game nextRound];
   [pool release];
}
```

Comment: It's actually not that big. The average number of rounds is about 20, and the maximum is 50. Anyway, I just tried that but the problem is still there, and there no leaks reported by instruments.